# Export interfaces from declared namespace

Tags: typescript

I can't understand why we use the `export` expression inside of a declared namespace. If we use the export or not, it's the same thing.

So, why we export something inside of a declared namespace?

```
 declare namespace Library{

    export interface Event {
        x: number;
        y: number;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to explicitly export it. In the example below the `export` keyword is left out, but we can still see the interface, and it still catches the type error on the last line.

```
 declare namespace Library {
    interface Event {
        x: number;
        y: number;
    }
}

const a: Library.Event = { x: 1, y: 1 };

const b: Library.Event = { x: 'f', y: 1 };
```